# PayPal gateway has rejected request

Tags: error, paypal, payment

I got the following message when trying to accept payment in Magento.

Does anyone know the cause of this error? It was working fine before I install a Paypal payment extension installed.
error msg:

```
PayPal gateway has rejected a request. The transaction has already been Accepted/Denied and the status cannot be changed (#11614: The transaction has already been Accepted/Denied and the status cannot be changed).
```

Comment: Which currency are you using?

Comment: I have also the same issue. Hi Mukesh we are using USD for seller account. the issue happens when the purchase happens with GBP

Answer (score 2):

This is because of currency mismatch in you store and business account you are using for getting payment.

You have to add currency in you seller account to accept store currency payment.

Here how the list of currency accept
https://prnt.sc/phymxt

You can add currency as many as you want by clicking `Currencies` link.

Comment: Last 2 years working good, suddenly facing this issue, may i know what is the main cause for this error? @Zaheerabbas

Comment: What i need to change, if change require how last 2 years working good? @Zaheerabbas

Comment: Did you change currency in your store? if yes then it may happened.

Comment: No, i did nothing. 4 days before working good, suddenly my payment gateway not working.

Answer (score 0):

## 11614: The transaction has already been Accepted/Denied and the status cannot be changed

Resovle:
We need create account base on curency of store

ex: if we use € => we  should use paypal business account  use € (should  select country finland)